Svelte: editablecontent and onChange
In svelte, I know that one can use editablecontent with bind:innerHTML to bind the content of a div with a variable. But in my case I want to modify the variable only when the div loses the focus (on:blur). So I tried to write this, inspired by what I do on input:
<script>
    let html = 'Write some text!';
</script>

If I change this:

<div innerHTML={html} on:blur={(e) => {html = e.target.innerHTML;}} contenteditable />

This one will not be updated, but ONLY after I click outside of the field (so bind:innerHTML is not what I want):

<div innerHTML={html} on:blur={(e) => {html = e.target.innerHTML;}} contenteditable />

{html}

<style>
    [contenteditable] {
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>


but this fail: the variable is modified on blur, but if the variable is changed from another field, it does not update its value.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

on:input={(e) => {html = e.target.innerHTML;}} ?
<div innerHTML={html}  on:input={(e) => {html = e.target.innerHTML;}}  contenteditable />


Thanks, unfortunately this does not solve the problem: as I explained, on:blur works, but the issue is on the innerHTML={html} part that does not work when html is updated.

ox,sry i missed first lines of your explanation

Welcome to SO! Sometimes the answer doesn't work out. I disagree with whoever downvoted this, since you are a new user and you were not able to comment. In the future, if you are not sure, a comment would be best once you get 50 reputation. Don't get discouraged by the downvote though! Ask some questions of your own and keep trying to provide help to others. Remember you can always ask a question that you're having and then when you find your own solution, you can provide that as the answer and mark it correct.

Ok, found the solution: innerHTML={html} does not work (no idea why), but I can directly insert the {html} inside the div like in:
<script>
    let html = 'Write some text!';
</script>

<div on:blur={(e) => {html = e.target.innerText;}} contenteditable>{html}</div>

<div on:blur={(e) => {html = e.target.innerText;}} contenteditable>{html}</div>

{html}

<style>
    [contenteditable] {
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>

https://svelte.dev/repl/30268a06642d4e3f98cfb88b242fe1bc?version=4.2.15

Some things can only be used with bind:, also some may only read from the element, not set a value (e.g. bind:clientWidth).

@brunnerh oh interesting… but if they can write & read it at the same time, why can't they do it in two times? Also, do you know If I could make a syntax that works like use:myBindOnChange={html} that sets both the on:blur and the property? I'd like to avoid the boiletrplate definition of the function etc. I tried but without success for now.

Using an action is not possible, unless you also pass in a function. The values are input-only.

Yeah it was my issue. So I guess bind is possible due to some internal compilation magic. Thanks!
